# StreamBuilder has data when it shouldn't

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Realtime database to add chat features to my app. In the database I have the following data:

```
{
    events: {
        "event-uuid1": {
            "chat-uuid1": {
                "message": "hey"
            },
            "chat-uuid2": {
                "message": "hey again"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my Flutter app, I have this StreamBuilder (I know this is lengthy, I'm not sure where the problem is so providing more rather than less):

```
class _EventChatScreenState extends ConsumerState<EventChatScreen> {
    FirebaseDatabase dbInstance = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
    late TextEditingController _messageFieldController;
    late DatabaseReference eventDbRef;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _messageFieldController = TextEditingController();
        eventDbRef = dbInstance.ref("none");
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        _messageFieldController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    Map<String, ChatMessage> chatMessages = {};

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final user = ref.watch(userProvider);
        final event = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as EventRepository;
        if (eventDbRef.path == "none") {
            print("IT IS NONE");
            eventDbRef = dbInstance.ref("/events/${event.event.eventId}/");
            print(eventDbRef.path); // Print's correct value
        }
        
        return StreamBuilder(
            stream: eventDbRef.onChildAdded,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (chatMessages == {}) {
                    return const Text("Loading...");
                }

                DatabaseEvent data;

                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    data = snapshot.data as DatabaseEvent;
                    ChatMessage newChatMessage = ChatMessage(
                        chatMessageId: "",
                        userId: "",
                        displayname: "",
                        message: "",
                        datetime: "",
                    );

                    for (var child in data.snapshot.children) {
                        switch (child.key) {
                            case "chatMessageId":
                                newChatMessage.chatMessageId = child.value.toString();
                            break;
                        case "userId":
                            newChatMessage.userId = child.value.toString();
                            break;
                        case "displayName":
                            newChatMessage.displayname = child.value.toString();
                            break;
                        case "message":
                            newChatMessage.message = child.value.toString();
                            break;
                        case "datetime":
                            final datetime = DateTime.parse(child.value.toString());
                            final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('h:mm aa');
                            final String formatted = formatter.format(datetime);
                            newChatMessage.datetime = formatted;
                            break;
                        default:
                    }
                }
   
                if (chatMessages[data.snapshot.key] == null) {
                    chatMessages[data.snapshot.key!] = newChatMessage;
                }
            }

            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: chatMessages.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                String key = chatMessages.keys.elementAt(index);
                if (chatMessages[key]!.userId == user.user.userId) {
                    return UnconstrainedBox(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                            child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                    Container(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                        child: Text(chatMessages[key]!.displayname),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 15),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(20),
                                            ),
                                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                                        ),
                                        child: Text(chatMessages[key]!.message,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                child: Text(chatMessages[key]!.datetime),
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            );
        }
    },
);
},
),
```

The problem is that when the user goes to the chat screen **one** of the messages will already be present in the chat. I would expect there to be nothing since I am not setting any initial data anywhere, not using Realtime Database's persistence, and not using my own local database yet.

My understanding of StreamBuilders is that they only get new data as it comes in, not data that may already exist and is thus not sent through it (Ie. when a new chat message is sent the stream should receive it, which works, but it should not receive chat message messages already in the database). If that understanding is wrong then why am I only getting one message despite there being 2, 3, 4, etc. in the database?

Perhaps I'm understanding/using StreamBuilders, Firebase Realtime Database, or both incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign this `eventDbRef.onChildAdded` to a variable in initState and then use the variable as your stream parameter in streambuilder. Having the db call in Streambuilder causes it to be rerun everytime the widget tree builds.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not so simple since I'm relying on data passed from another screen. I updated the question to show what's going on at the top of this widget's state. I updated to do what you suggested, but still not working.

Comment: I use stream builder and RTDB for the chat part of my app. I use .onValue rather than onChildAdded but I don't think that is the issue. You probably need to look at how you are getting the data you need from the other screen. You should have that data available to initState and not have to receive it in the build method, imho.

Comment: how do you pass it through? I'm doing so using the `arguments` param on the `pushNamed` method and receiving it on the following screen with `ModalRoute.of(context)`

Comment: The arguments you pass through routing are received by the page you call. You define variables for them after the class statement in the page and then reference them as `widget.<variable name> see https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: Thanks. That's what I followed, however they access them in the build method.

Comment: You can access them anywhere. In their example if you `print(widget.title)` in initState it will output the value...which means you can use it there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your understanding about streambuilder is wrong.

Lets say you use `FutureBuilder`, It'll wait till the future is over and then builds the widget accordingly but It'll not build again if something changes in your database, but for `StreamBuilder`, It'll basically listen (and get initial data from stream, here your `db`) to the stream and build whenever it changes or a new data is added to stream (here `database`) it will get the updated data and build the widget again.

Read here:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes

Comment: This link takes me to docs for Firestore. Is this applicable to Realtime Database?

Comment: Yup, it's the same for Realtime Database. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_data for that, specifically: "This event **is triggered once when the listener is attached** and again every time the data, including any children, changes."